# How can I get file mtime in python for a large file on AIX

Tags: python, aix

I need to get the file modification time for a ~5GB file on an AIX system with Python 2.6.7 without large file support. `os.stat` and `os.path.getmtime` don't work as the file size is too large. ("OSError: [Errno 127] Value too large to be stored in data type")

Which other possibilities do I have?

Comment: Why don't you call out to `ls -l` and then parse its output?

Comment: i could, but that's ugly.

Comment: also, it's not locale independent.

Comment: Use the `ctypes` module to call the appropriate C library functions?

Comment: @larsks sounds interesting, would you have an example implementation?

Comment: Not for AIX, no.  There are some examples in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html), and also [here](https://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/interfacing_with_c/interfacing_with_c.html#id5), and I've written something [for Linux](https://github.com/larsks/python-netns/blob/master/netns.py).

Comment: hm, tried this now, but my installation (which i have no control over) has no _ctypes :(

Comment: Try to install/compile a 64-bit version of Python.